# Feature request: Review posts notification

Tags: feature-request

I recently noticed a Review tab in the menu bar in SO, [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276582/how-to-check-if-posts-are-waiting-a-review).

There isn't a way to know, if posts are awaiting to be reviewed. I think it would be useful to be alerted to posts that are waiting in the queue to be reviewed. I have not found a duplicate question, so if this is a duplicate. Please let me know I will remove it.

Comment: On busy sites you'll soon wish you never asked for this. Reviews are coming in **all the time**.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily mean you have to review every single one? @MartijnPieters

Comment: You don't get to pick what you review, other than that you can skip what you've been asked to review when you clicked on the link.

Comment: I understand, but you get a notification on ie. reputation points gained, surely a feature to see a notification like that can't seem too pestering?

Comment: Those reputation points are *just for you*. Reviews are for anyone willing to pick them up. Note that a) there already is a reviews-pending counter in the top bar, for example. It is heavily cached because a *huge number of people* see that counter and recalculating it for everyone all the time simply doesn't scale. The number of people that need notifying for each review task coming in would also be humongous.

Comment: Oh i see, so reviews are sent to everyone and whoever is willing to pick it up. Yep makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts are ready for review just about *all the time*. On many sites you can easily take your fill of reviews simply by visiting the *review* link once in a while. Notifications would quickly drown you out.

Moreover, there are plenty of people willing to review; why should individuals be notified of reviews coming in? And there are plenty of people that do not *want* to review, pestering them is not going to change that. This is quite apart from scaling issues; on Stack Overflow there are 121k accounts with access to the review queues, sending 121k notifications each time something is ready for review is simply not feasible.

If you really want to 'snipe' reviews, use a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script) to reload the reviews page every so often.

Comment: accepted 6 years later... :P